# oracle Tuxedo cleint in java

Tags: oracle, maven, jar, tuxedo

I am trying to write one simple oracle Tuxedo client in Java , with Jolt Class Library. 
I got the sample code in BEA documentation. But I am not able to find out required jars anywhere.

```
import bea.jolt.*;
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    JoltSession session;
    JoltSessionAttributes sattr;
    JoltRemoteService withdrawal;
    JoltRemoteService deposit;
    JoltTransaction trans;
```

Can anyone help me out by pointing the required jar location to download or maven repo link , if available.

Answer (score 1):

The jars (jolt.jar) are part of the Tuxedo Download. See **Oracle Tuxedo 12cR2 (12.2.2) (Including Tuxedo, SALT and Jolt)** in https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/tuxedo/downloads/index.html

If you don't want to install Tuxedo you may extract the jar with

```
jar -xf ./stage/Components/joltClient/12.2.2.0.0/1/DataFiles/filegroup1.1.1.jar jolt.jar
```